# Why won't my function change object value?

Tags: javascript

Why does the `add()` function have no effect on LIST? What I'm trying to create is this:[image]

```
function arrayToList(array){
    LIST = {};
    function add(list, index){
        if(index < array.length){
            list = {value:array[index], rest : null};
            add(list.rest, index+1);
        }
    }
    add(LIST,0);
    return LIST;
}
```

Comment: Inside add, you will have access to LIST variable itself since add is a private method. That should work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your code is written as if JavaScript were a pass-by-reference language. It is not.

Specifically, inside your `add()` function, your code is written as if making an assignment to the parameter `list` will have an affect on what was passed into the function as an argument; it will not.  That is, this statement:

```
        list = {value:array[index], rest : null};
```

will modify the value of the parameter, but it will not affect the global variable `LIST`.

There are different ways you could redesign the code. Here's one way:

```
function arrayToList(array){
    function add(index){
        var entry = null;
        if (index < array.length) {
            entry = { value: array[index], rest: add(index + 1) };
        }
        return entry;
    }
    return add(0);
}
```

Comment: Since I cannot pass the object by reference, does it mean there's no way around it? I tried another way of making the same thing using a for loop instead of the add() function and it worked but I was trying to do it using recursion.

Comment: @shauryagupta I've updated the answer with a recursive alternative that should work.

Answer (score 1):

First off, you'll want to slap a `var` in front of `LIST` so that you aren't creating a global variable.

```
function arrayToList(array) {
  var LIST = {};
  ...
}
```

Next, the issue is that when you pass in `list.rest`, you aren't passing a reference to that property. You're just passing the value of `null`. Instead, you may want to try creating a node at the end but set the value to `null`.

```
function arrayToList(array) {
  var LIST = {};
  function add(list, index) {
    if (index < array.length) {
      list.value = array[index];
      list.rest = {};
      add(list.rest, index + 1);
    } else {
      list.rest = list.value = null;
    }
  }
  add(LIST, 0);
  return LIST;
}
```

Edit: Or if you want to make certain the end is `null`, you could perform a simple check inside of your `add` function.

```
function add(list, index) {
  if (index < array.length) {
    list.value = array[index];
    if (index + 1 < array.length) {
      list.rest = {};
      add(list.rest, index + 1);
    } else {
      list.rest = null;
    }
  }
}
```